# How does Linux verify the login password?

Tags: linux, password, shadow

I would like to know how the password verification in Linux works.

I know that the passwords are stored as a hash in `/etc/shadow` file and user information is in `/etc/passwd` file. My understanding is this:

1. Selecting what user you want to login as decides what user name the system should check.
2. When you enter the password and hit enter, the system goes to the `/etc/shadow` file and finds the line corresponding to the user name.
3. From step 2 it gets the hash of the actual password. It then generates the hash of the entered password and compares both of them. If a match is found, voilà. Else, error message.

Is my understanding correct?

Comment: `Linux` in a kernel found on many very different operating systems, it doesn't deal with user passwords. Please specify the Linux-based operating system you're talking about (Debian, Android, ChromeOS, Fedora, OpenWRT...). Only some systems (and only in some deployments) use `/etc/passwd,shadow` to store user information

Comment: It's often the PAM security module.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. You're correct. Each steps can be split in minor tasks as well, but you describe the overall algorithm.

Follow a couple of articles describing in details the login process. [[1]](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/3121) [[2]](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/howlinuxworks/linux_hllogin.html)

Note that this is only about the plain password, not mentioning PAM system. [[3]](http://www.linux-pam.org/)

Comment: and which script does this verification? The name of the script I mean :)

Comment: @LittleChild I doubt it's a script. It's an application which provides login prompt `/sbin/mingetty` or `/sbin/agetty` mostly.

Comment: @UVV No, not getty. Getty is basically a loop running forever on a terminal. For each login prompt, getty runs `login`, and that's the program that performs the authentication (for a text mode console login).

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for the correction. It's not a script anyway ;)